# how to add title to Gtk.MessageDialog

Tags: python, dialog, gtk, title, pygtk

I've been trying to add a title to my dialog messages in python but I couldn't do it .

This is my code:

```
dialog=Gtk.MessageDialog(None, 0, Gtk.MessageType.ERROR, Gtk.ButtonType.OK, "wrong password")
dialog.run()
dialog.close()
```

Comment: http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtkmessagedialog.html

Comment: pygtk is a dead, the real docs are: http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gtk-3.0/classes/MessageDialog.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set it with :

```
dialog.set_title ("My app name")
```